# Swift 3 Closure

Tags: swift, closures

In Swift 3 can I use string-specific implementation in trailing closure?

```
let names = ["Ekram","Galib","Hasan","Rangon","Asif","Saikat"]

let reversedName = names.sorted{ > }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wrap the `>` in a trailing closure? `sorted(by:)` takes a function and `>` already matches its signature. So just do:

```
let reversedName = names.sorted(by: >)
```

Just to state maybe non-obvious things:

a) Operators in Swift work like regular functions, e.g. in this case sth like `func > <T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool`

b) In Swift functions are named closures, if an API expects a closure (like `(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool`), you can also use a named function, like `>` or `func compareTheTwo(a: String, b: String) -> Bool`

Comment: Closures aren't anonymous functions – functions are named closures.

Comment: If you nitpick, be exact: `functions are named closures IN SWIFT` ;-)

Comment: @hnh Well I thought context was enough for that bit ;)

Comment: I doubt for many context is enough to even understand what you have been saying, i.e. what is the difference between an anonymous function and a closure. And BTW your statement isn't completely right either given that Swift can also invoke pure functions (like `strcmp` or Swift global functions which do not capture). I think the appropriate statement would be more like: a Swift function declaring a callback entry point like `( String, String ) -> Void` accepts all, a closure, a method or a function. All that has little relevance for the original question though.

Comment: @hnh Oh we've opened up a can of worms here :) In Swift, a closure doesn't mean something that does capture – it simply means a self-contained chunk of code which *can* capture variables from the enclosing scope, regardless of its purity. A function is a named closure, and a closure expression (the use of curly braces to create a closure inline) is an anonymous closure. I agree it is quite confusing, especially as these definitions conflict with other language's definitions – I take your point about perhaps expanding a bit more on my first comment, which I hope this comment has now done.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, but you have to specify which arguments to it you’re actually comparing:

```
let reversedNames = names.sorted { $0 > $1 }
```

Comment: Or `names.sorted(by: >)`